# Selenium - Wait for Javascript function to execute before continuing

Tags: java, javascript, function, selenium, wait

I'm currently creating some test cases with Selenium and I've come across a problem.

In my test case, the website I'm trying to walk through has a small form and a button to search. No problem filling the form and clicking the button. The problem comes once clicking the problem.

Once clicked the button, this function is called:

```
function muestraEspera(){
document.getElementById("divCargando").style.display = "";
}
```

Basically, this makes visible a DIV which contains an "loading" image so the visitor do just see the image and wont be able to actually see the website loading the content until finished (the content is loaded with ajax).

Once the content is loaded, this function is executed:

```
function escondeEspera(){
document.getElementById("divCargando").style.display = "none";
}
```

Which basically hides the "loading" DIV so the visitor can see the results.

Now, I can't use SLEEPS because loading can take more or less, and because I need the real execution time of the website. Is there any way (using java - junit4) to make selenium wait until the second function is executed before continuing with the next steps?

EDIT: I do use Selenium RC. To start the driver I use:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "website-url");
        selenium.start();
    }
```

**At the end, the solution that worked perfectly for me, given by Pavel Janicek is:**

```
boolean doTheLoop = true;
      int i = 0;
      while (doTheLoop){      
      i= i+200;
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      if (i>30000){
        doTheLoop = false;
      }
      if (!selenium.isVisible("id=divCargando")){
         doTheLoop = false;
      }      
      if (selenium.isVisible("id=divCargando")){
             doTheLoop = true;
          }      
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** EDIT 3**

So we have:

```
DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*iexplore", "websiteURL");
```

Still you can use the command `isVisible` like this:

```
boolean doTheLoop = true;
    int i = 0;
    while (doTheLoop){      
        i = i+200;
        Thread.sleep(200);
        if (i>30000){
            doTheLoop = false;
        }
        if (!selenium.isVisible("id=the ID Of element")){
            doTheLoop = false;
      }      
}
```

Hope you will not end up in infinite loop.

I never worked with DefaultSelenium, so use please the `isVisible()` function the same way as you are using the `click()` for example.

Comment: Both methods give me these errors: "driver cannot be resolved" and "The method isVisible() is undefined for the type WebElement"..

Comment: I forgot to mention - the `driver` is instance of WebDriver. I will update the answer a little.

Comment: I do use: selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "website-url"); To start the driver. Selenium RC.

Comment: Editing once more. I will provide the quickest solution found: `WebDriver driver = selenium.getWrappedDriver();`

Comment: Just one problem using this solution: "The method getWrappedDriver() is undefined for the type Selenium"

Comment: Darn! I provided you the answer for WebDriverBackedSelenium class, which I am using sometimes. Never worked with DefaultSelenium class. Will have to look...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked great! I just added: if (selenium.isVisible("id=divCargando")){ doTheLoop = true;} This way once the div is hidden, next step is done like a charm! Thank you very much!

Comment: Uff! At least something :) Happy testing to you ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [waitForCondition](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/waitForCondition)
And if you're using WebDriver, you can try WebDriverBackedSelenium or FluentWait.
I think [this link](http://www.tarnowski.se/2011/09/11/converting-selenium-waitforcondition-to-webdriverwait/) will help.

Comment: How would you use it? I tried it with waitForCondition and I could not get it to work... :(

Comment: The waitForCondition seems to be Selenium-IDE related. Will not work if you use WebDriver approach.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this. It waits until the specified timeout. And what it waits for is specified in the FluentWait-object. It waits until the Boolean gets true. So if your element is not visible any more, the Boolean gets true and the method stops waiting. The nice thing about this is that it only asks every 1 second if your element is visible instead of asking as fast as it can which makes no sense.

```
public static void wait(WebDriver driver, int timeout, final By locator){
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)

    wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
            return !element.isDisplayed();
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: As you wrote in your comments and in your edit, it seems that you use Selenium 1. WebDriver is part of Selenium 2. So just get the wrapped driver like this:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "website-url");
CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(selenium); 
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, new DesiredCapabilities());
```

Comment: Using -----  FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
          .withTimeout(200, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

       wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
           public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
               WebElement element = driver.findElement(divCargando);
               return !element.isDisplayed();
           }
       });  ----- I do get this error: "Driver cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace? driver is an WebDriver instance, like FirefoxDiver or RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: The thing is that I use selenium RC: selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "website-url");

Comment: Or more generally - can you provide how do you initialize the WebDriver?

Comment: You use Selenium 1. Just add the following after your DefaultSelenium: CommandExecutor executor =
    new SeleneseCommandExecutor(selenium);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor,
    new DesiredCapabilities());

Comment: Here I do get: "RemoteWebDriver cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: are you sure you imported org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver ?

Comment: SORRY!! I missed that one. I imported it and that error disappeared. Now the only error left is: "The type Function is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <WebDriver, Boolean>".

Comment: Sure it can. the code which I posted works. Are you sure we are talking about the same Function-class? It is com.google.common.base.Function. And furthermore this thread is gonna turn into a Java-coding problem than the original problem with selenium. I tested the code I posted and it works and solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But at the end the solution provided by Pavel Janicek worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :D I would give you a PLUS vote, but I haven't got enough rep.. :(

Comment: Can't mark two answers as solution. And the other one worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Thats what I meant. Mark HIS answer as solution. not mine.